# Looping inside r.mapcalc in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, classification, resampling

I have a Land Cover classification map that I created from 2m resolution multispectral imagery and I am trying to downsample the results to a 20m resolution class map.

The climate in question is arid so there are many areas with sparse shrubs or trees. As such, one 2m resolution class may have a couple of pixels for a single shrub. I am not interested in where each individual tree or bush is, but rather where there are areas of high concentration of a given class (i.e. I want to create a 20m resolution class map that will aggregate the high resolution classes into classes such as "sparse shrubs" or "dense shrubs" depending on the density of 2m x 2m shrub classes found in the 20m x 20m grid square)

Using r.mapcalc in GRASS GIS I know you can refer to neighboring cells using the format map[1,-2] and there are many useful functions available in r.mapcalc. However, my problem is that when I am downsampling to ~20m resolution from 2m resolution there are ~100 neighbors to analyze and I would have to address each one specifically as there is no way that I have found to nest a for loop within a call to r.mapcalc.

Does anyone have suggestions on a way to gather statistics of the cells surrounding a given map cell, and change the cell in question based on its neighbors in the way I describe?

Comment: If you think that is necessary to use a loop with `r.mapcal` then you need some script language. In Linux, you can use bash script and, in Windows, a bat file. Another option is using grass.script with python where the sintaxis of r.mapcalc changes to 'grass.mapcalc'. However, I would use GDAL-Python. You can see this approach: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72150/how-to-find-buffer-radius-around-raster-cell-that-covers-a-defined-sum-of-raster/134477#134477. The 3x3 block can be changed for a 10x10 block (100 neighbors).

Comment: @xunilk: I saw some examples of people using scripts to run r.mapcalc multiple times, but it didn't seem like that afforded the flexibility I needed when it came to what r.mapcalc was doing on a specific pass. However, your suggestion of using GDAL has been very helpful so far! Thank you

Comment: Don't you want to be using ``r.resample`` or ``r.neighbors`` with method=mode?

Comment: @Micha: That doesn't accomplish my purpose and I do not just want to know the most common value within my window. Instead, I would like to be able to tabulate how many of each class type are within the window. For example, 80% of the cells are sand and 20% of the cells have a class type of shrub. Then in my aggregrate 20m x 20m class map I can equate that  20m resolution cell to "shrub, sparse". Your suggestion would only yield "sand" which is of less interest to me.

Comment: I guess I didn't quite understand your question. If you want to do any kind of weighted average of the Landcover classifications then you'll loose the classifications. Do you already have in mind a set of new classifications such as "sparse vegetation", "dense vegetation" with the values that you expect, as percents of the original classes?

Comment: You could also use 'r.resamp.stats' with weighing (-w), see http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Interpolation#Resampling_of_raster_maps_to_coarser_resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @xunilk suggested, I found GDAL to be the tool I was looking for. I also used Counter to create a form of histogram that helped me complete my analysis.

```
for i in xrange(0,iRange,resampleInterval):
    for j in xrange(0,jRange,resampleInterval):
        scanline = band.ReadRaster(i, j, windowSize, windowSize, windowSize, windowSize, band.DataType)
        neighbors = struct.unpack(fmtTypes[BandType] * windowSizeSquared, scanline)
        neighborData = Counter(neighbors)
        statsTuple = neighborData.most_common() # Returns all unique items and their counts [(4,101),(1,50)]
        numNeighbors = sum(neighborData.values()) # sum(neighborData.values()) yields number of neighbors
        # findClass assigns classID based on percent of total area each class makes up
        classID = findClass(statsTuple, numNeighbors, classID, 'Roads')
        classID = findClass(statsTuple, numNeighbors, classID, 'Water')

        classID = findClass(statsTuple, numNeighbors, classID, 'Forest')
        classID = findClass(statsTuple, numNeighbors, classID, 'Shrub')
        # If mixture does not fit into one of the above buckets, set class equal to the mode of the window
        if not classID:
            classID = statsTuple[0][0] # Set classID equal to mode of neighbors
        classArray.append((i+1,j+1,classID)) #save x,y coordinate with classID
```